# Horizontal Timeline marked in hour and minute

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I need help to put up Horizontal Timeline marked in hour and minute,please help

Comment: I need it to start at 7:00 and end on 7:30 while 7:15 will be inbetween

Answer (score 3):

```
     \documentclass{article}
     \usepackage{tikz}


     \begin{document}

     \begin{tikzpicture}
     % draw horizontal line   

      \draw (0,0) -- (8,0);



      % draw vertical lines
       \foreach \x in {0,4,8}
       \draw (\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt);

        % draw nodes
       \draw (0,0) node[below=3pt] {7:00 } node[above=3pt] {Start};
       \draw (4,0) node[below=3pt] {7:15} node[above=3pt] {Middle};
       \draw (8,0) node[below=3pt] {7:30} node[above=3pt] {End};

       \end{tikzpicture}

       \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If it works then please click on the left side this answer is useful and click on green tick to accept answer @economia

Comment: Why would you use `{$ \rm Start $}` instead of just `{Start}`? *Start* isn't math, it's text, and `\rm` has been considered deprecated for over twenty years ...

Comment: yes @Torbjørn T, this can be used for notation like V_{1} or V^{1} thats why $ sign is used here, if we don't want we can remove $ sign also.

Comment: I don't understand your point. There are no subscripts or superscripts in start, middle and end, so there is no reason for using math mode in the first place.

Comment: @BikiTeron How would one new ling for text? For example `\draw (0,0) node[below=3pt] {7:00 } node[above=3pt] {Lesson\\starts};`